# How do I edit grub.cfg and save it?

Tags: linux, grub

I want to make an edit to /boot/grub/grub.cfg . I save the file and run sudo update-grub.  But when I  reboot, the old version is still being used by grub.  So it seems update-grub is not using this file. How should I really do this?
(I can press 'e' at the command line and edit the entry. But there seems no way to save this, and I don't want to keep making the edit each time I boot).

Comment: Have a look at https://askubuntu.com/questions/437323/is-it-possible-to-edit-grub-cfg

Answer (score 6):

`update-grub` uses `grub.cfg` - it re-generates it. To the regeneration, it uses

- list of your kernel/initrd images in `/boot`
- configuration in `/etc/default/grub`
- and the configuration generator scripts in `/etc/grub.d`.

To change `grub.cfg` permanently, you can do one of these:

- Not using `update-grub` any more (painful)
- Editing the files/configs above (need a little learning, but not too much)
- Switching to another boot manager, for example to LILO (all have advantages and disadvantages - grub is only the most popular today, becase it integrates best with easy-to-use distros)

Answer (score 3):

Well to my surprise I found that running:

```
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

before running `update-grub` fixed the problem I had.  This seems inexplicable since it seems that update-grub looks as though it is calling grub-mkconfig.  Anyway now my edits to 40_custom etc are being picked up.

Thanks to all for helpful responses.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a custom menu to `/etc/grub.d/40_custom`, it will be added to `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` file after `update-grub`.

explained here : [Configuring GRUB v2](https://wiki.debian.org/Grub#Configuring_GRUB_v2):

> The configuration file is `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`, but you shouldn't edit
>   it directly. This file is generated by grub v2's `update-grub`(8), based
>   on:
>
> 1. The script snippets in `/etc/grub.d/`
> 2. The configuration file `/etc/default/grub`
>
> To configure grub "v2", you should edit `/etc/default/grub`, then run
>   `update-grub`. Advanced configuration are achieved by modifying the
>   snippets in `/etc/grub.d/`.